# obtain the id of an element created with rest api in the same session

Tags: php, api

I'm creating a message on the forum using the rest api:

```
  $point = '/forums/topics';
  $endpoint = $url. 'api'. $point. '?key='. $apiKey;

  $options = [
               'form_params' => [
                 'forum' => 3,
                 'title' => $request->title,
                 'post' => $request->body,
                 'author' => 1
               ]
 ];
 $client = new Client();
 $request =  $client->post($endpoint, $options);
```

From this API I would need to create the ID to be able to store it in $article->id_topic

but I can't find out how I can go back to the ID of the item created with POST.

I've already done some tests, failing, here are some:

```
$article->id_topic = $request->id;
```

and with json_decode

```
 $id_topic = json_decode($request);
 $idt = $request->id;

 $articoli->id_topic = $idt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $id_topic = json_decode($request->getBody());
 $article->id_topic = $id_topic->id;
 $article->save();
```